# Using ToList() when copying Lists

Tags: c#, visual-studio, list

I have a program in C# (Visual Studio) and part of the code looks like this:

Class 1:

```
private void part_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> parameters = part.selectedParameters;
    // Lots of code
    List<string> allParameters = parameters.ToList(); 

    for (int k = 0; k < limit; k++)
    {
        allParameters.Add("text");
    }    
}
```

Class 2:

```
public bool DoAnalysis()
{
     List<string> partParameters = part.selectedParameters;
     // Lots of code
     List<string> allPartParameters = partParameters; 

     for (int k = 0; k < limit; k++)
     {
        allPartParameters.Add("text");
     }  
}
```

My question is concerning the use of `ToList()`. I want to copy List1 to List2 and working with List2 without List1 being changed too. Applying this to my code, I used `.ToList()` to deal with this. Adding `ToList()` was not a problem in Class 1 --> `parameters.ToList()` but when I want to add it in Class 2 to `List<string> allPartParameters = partParameters`, it is not possible. I only get the options `ToArray()` and `ToString()`.

So, why can I add `ToList()` to a List in one part of the code and not in the other? Am I missing some property dependency somewhere else in the code?

Comment: `using System.Linq`

Comment: You can also do: `var allPartParameters = new List<string>(partParameters):`

Comment: I don't agree that this is a duplicate. The answer is the same but the question is not. I know that I have to use ToList() but it wasn't able to select it, while in the suggested question, the person didn't know how to create (a copy of) a List.

Comment: @MXD Thanks, I didn't realize I put System.Linq in comment because I wasn't using it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually with dependency problems you can right click the red highlighted code and choose "Quick Actions and Refactoring" then a list will come up of dependencies you can possibly use. This will save you time typing it and has helped me tons.